# JDialog: Prevent parent frame to be closed

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe, jdialog

How can invalidate focus from parent frame? I have a `JFrame` (`parentFrame`), and I am opening a `JDialog` as:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame);
```

Now I need to set the dialog is such a way that, whenever trying someone click the parent frame it always put focus on that dialog, even resist the parent frame to be closed.

As an example, while you are adding an Environmental Variable in Windows (System Properties->Advanced Tab->Environmental Variables button click), the Environmental Variable window resist its parent to be close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the dialog [modal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 3):

You can make the Dialog modal.  There is a utility [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#Dialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) which does this for you:

```
JDialog(parent, title, modal);
```

or you can call the setModal function on the dialog.

Comment: +1 See also the other [`Dialog` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#constructor_summary), 5 of which accept a `boolean` to specify modality, and 3 of which accept a [`Dialog.ModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html).